# Interpolating implied volatility term structure when IV is sampled at fixed delta points

Tags: options, implied-volatility, volatility-surface

According to [the accepted answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/22263/64701) to a question in this site on the interpolation in the term structure of volatility surface:

> A simple linear interpolation on implied variance along iso-moneyness lines is enough to guarantee that there is no arbitrage between maturities as long as the inputted market data is arbitrage free.

In my case, however, I have implied volatilities sampled at fixed delta points for a set of maturities $\{ T_i \}$. If I linearly interpolate the implied *variance* at a time $T$, where $T_i \leq T \leq T_{i+1}$, along ***iso-delta*** lines, will the time-interpolated results at $T$ for all delta points be arbitrage free?

My guess is yes, but I'm hoping someone can confirm. In the Black-Scholes model, the delta of a call option is $\Delta = N(d_1)$ where $N()$ represents the cumulative normal probability density function with $$d_1 = \frac{\log(S_0/K) + (r + \sigma^2/2)T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}.$$

Because $N()$ is monotonic and non-decreasing, I'm hoping the arbitrage-free result would still be maintained. I would much appreciate if anyone can confirm or refute this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iso-moneyness approach guarantees no arbitrage in terms of calendar spreads, but it is not proven it does not introduce some butterfly spreads at some interpolated time. See [Arbitrages in the Volatility Surface Interpolation and Extrapolation](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2175001).

Using iso-delta is sometimes done, not for arbitrage concerns, but because it may make more sense from a financial perspective. It does not guarantee the absence of calendar spread arbitrage. It would be interesting to find a counter example. $N()$ is monotonic but $\sigma$ is not. The no-arbitrage condition is derived in [Arbitrage-free conditions for implied volatility surface by Delta](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1062940818301074) does not look nice

Arbitrages with iso-delta interpolation is usually not a concern even if it may happen in not-so-realistic/manufactured examples.